# c language compound assignment, how is v += e different from v = v + e?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

In chapter 4, section Compound Assignment of the book: C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition, says:

> Note that I've been careful not to say that `v += e` is “equivalent” to `v = v + e`. One problem is operator precedence: `i * = j + k` isn't the same as `i = i * j + k`.

I write a program to compare `i * = j + k` with `i = i * j + k`.
but the result is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    i *= j + 10;
    int k = 1;
    k = k * j + 10;
    printf("j=%d k=%d\n", i, k);
}
```

### result is:

> j=12 k=12

So my question is: why isn't `i * = j + k` the same as `i = i * j + k` ?

Thanks for all the replies. I have misunderstood the compound assignment operator. And I have wrote a misleading test.
I'd like to say you guys are great to discuss technical questions and learn together. I can not find such a great website and people like you in China.

Comment: order of operations.

Comment: Chen Li: **try different values!**

Comment: Also, j = 2.  You mixed up your `i` and `j`.

Comment: the order of operations is  i = i * j + k, is i = (i*j) + k, what about i *= j + k? I'm a little confused

Comment: `i *= j + k;` is the same as `i = i * (j + k);`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your explain!

Comment: @StoryTeller: that's why I tend to test with prime numbers: `i = 7; j = 13; k = 11; ...` anyway, close vote retracted (and comment deleted)

Comment: Why was this closed? It contains a minimal and complete example to reproduce the problem. It is perfectly clear what the question is.

Answer (score 6):

If you get confused, have a look at the [operator precedence chart](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

In your case,

```
i *= j + 10;
```

is same as

```
i *= (j + 10);
```

which is same as

```
i = i * (j + 10);
```

However,

```
k = k * j + 10;
```

is same as

```
k = (k * j) + 10;
```

As per the output: **Try different values.**

For example, if I chose `i` and `k` as `2`, the output will be

> i=24 k=14

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

It is quite obvious that they refer to operator precedence. That is:

- The expression `i = i * j + k` is equivalent to `i = (i * j) + k`.
- But `i *= j + k` is equivalent to `i = i * (j + k);`.

Now of course if you use bad input such as `i=1, j=1, k=1` the result of both of these expressions will be the same, by bad luck. Not because of the C language but because of elementary school math.

(if you are a beginner you can stop reading here)

---

Advanced answer regarding equivalence of assignment operators:

Compound assignment (the `*=`) is not exactly equivalent to simple assignment `=`. The standard C17 6.5.16.2 says:

> A *compound assignment* of the form **E1 *op* = E2** is equivalent to the simple assignment expression **E1 = E1 *op* (E2)**, except that the lvalue **E1** is evaluated only once

Meaning that if reading the operand E1 includes a side effect, compound assignment is different from simple assignment. Consider this artificial but valid example:

```
int foo (void)
{
  static int n=0;
  return ++n;
}

int array[3] = {1,2,3};
int* ptr = array;

#define FOO *(ptr + foo())
```

`FOO += 1;` gives an array `1 3 3` but `FOO = FOO + 1;` could give an array `1 4 3` <sup>1)</sup>. This is because of the extra side-effect in the latter case.

---

<sup>1)</sup> The order of evaluation between the left FOO and right FOO is unspecified, so it can give different results - it is unspecified behavior.

Comment: `FOO = FOO + 1` has unspecified results, no?

Comment: @StoryTeller The evalution of left FOO vs right FOO isn't sequenced but there is a sequence point before each function call. So yeah it is unspecified behavior. I should probably add a note about that, thanks.